# Installing Sql Management Studio Express in English

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a French OS (XP) and also "Microsoft Sql Management Studio Express" that is in French.

Now, I decided to install the English version of this software.
So, I downloaded the [English](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796) version of the Studio. Finished the installation, but it is always in French...

Why? How to "fix" it?

Comment: It is in French, because... well you know how the French are about speaking French ;)

Comment: @Ivo: Yes)  but, fortunately, Microsoft is not a French company...

Comment: That would be the only reason for me to switch to mysql;) But sorry I cant help you with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use "Your Uninstaller" to have the "really" complete list of installed software. Apparently is not the case with "Add and Remove Programs" util.

After that I saw two instances of Management Studio... I uninstalled both and reinstalled the English one. Now, I have a English version of the software.